# How can I check the smallest spacing between any two elements from two separate arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take for example two arrays

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

b = np.array([3.5, 5, 6, 7])
```

The smallest spacing can be found between both the 3rd and 4th element in `a` and the 1st element in `b`. The value of interest is `0.5`.

A brute force method would be to iterate through every value in `a` and `b`, and find the minimal value. But this is computationally heavy if the arrays are large; e.g. flatted images.

Are there more efficient ways to determine the value?

Comment: Definitely not the best answer, but this sounds like a suited problem for Numba if a better algorithm is not proposed.

Comment: @Tian So, if the inputs are images, would they be int arrays? If so, we could optimize with that in mind.

Comment: For now they are 32 bit floating point images. But the values of the pixels range from 0 - 1.605 if i recall correctly. I am trying to find the spacing between the values so that I can convert them to a 32bit uint image, or even an 8bit uint image if there are no losses